# pytest unittest custom decorator change unittest execution order

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I am using pytest to test firmware functionality on a microcontroller. The interface to it is irrelevant for this conversation.
As such, I have a number of checks which I include at the end of every unittest to ensure that the microcontroller is still in a valid state.

Now, these checks are common to every unittest, to be executed at the end of execution of each unittest. I thought it would make sense to use a decorator for this and decorate each unittest instead of duplicating code.

This works except now, unittest execution is no longer in sequence. Unittests now seem to be executed randomly instead of the order in which they were defined which was the behavior before I introduced the decorator.

Could someone please tell me why this happening?

Example pseudocode:

```
def check_no_err(func):
    def checker(api, *args, **kwargs):
        func(api, *args, **kwargs)
        assert 1 #<some checker code here run after the unittest>

@check_no_err
def test_eval_status(api):
    assert 1 #unittest body here
```

**edit**: I am using a fixture with a function scope to achieve the same behavior which provides predictable unit test execution order. Like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def test_end_checker(api):
    assert 1 #the check to run after every test which includes this fixture
```

So the only remaining question is why execution order is being randomized due to the additional decorator.

Comment: I hit similar issue when attempting to use a custom decorator; test order was dictated by function name and no longer followed function order.   Conceptually, this makes sense given the custom decorator has altered the code location.  All decorated functions point to the same invocation point which hinders pytest's ability to discern code location.